# prop is not reactive when passed down in render function

Tags: vuejs3, vue-render-function

Reproducer: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-tjt1qp?file=src/components/ParentComponent.js

In the reproducer above, I expect the child to behave in the same way as the parent.

I am trying to pass props via render functions to child components.

```js
const submitting = ref('...');
const childComponent = h(ChildComponent, { loading: submitting.value });

return () => h('div', props, [slots.default(), childComponent]);
```

However, they are not reactive. I read the [vuejs docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/render-function.html)  on render functions, but couldn't find out what I am doing wrong. Obviously I am missing something... what is it?

Answer (score 2):

Someone in the vuejs dischord channel helped me out.

Instead of writing

```js
const childComponent = h(ChildComponent, { loading: submitting.value });

// render function
return () => h('div', props, [slots.default(), childComponent]);
```

In the example above, the `childComponent`'s vNode is created only once. This is because setup functions are called once, while render functions get called multiple times, see. e.g., [vueJs docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/render-function.html#declaring-render-functions) on declaring render functions. I need to make sure that the `childComponent`'s vNode is re-rendered by shifting it inside the render function:

```js
// render function
return () => {
  const childComponent = h(ChildComponent, { loading: submitting.value });
  return h('div', props, [slots.default(), childComponent]);
}
```

Alternatively, I could call the the hyperscript function `h()` inside the parents hyperscript function:

```js
// render function
return () => h(
    'div',
    props,
    [
        slots.default(),
        h(ChildComponent, { loading: submitting.value })
    ]
);
```

Or, when assigning the child component's hyperscript function to a variable, wrap it inside a function

```js
const childComponent = function () {
    return h(ChildComponent, { loading: submitting.value });
};
// render function
return () => h('div', props, [slots.default(), childComponent()]);
```

Comment: not working for me, move the child component's render function inside the parent's render function? Instead of having  a variable render function you just inlined it?

Comment: mhh... difficult to judge for me w/o looking at your code. you might wanna fork and play around with my stackblitz reproducer linked above. https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-tjt1qp?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FParentComponent.js

Comment: i updated the answer; i hope it becomes more apparent now. i distinguished the two concepts "render function" and "hyperscript function"/ "vNode creation". also, i added an example of how to move the vNode creation of `childComponent` inside the render function

Answer (score 0):

```
const childComponent = h(ChildComponent, { loading: submitting.value });
```

replace with

```
 const childComponent = h=>(h(ChildComponent, { loading: submitting.value }));
```

It works may be like computed.